# Sitecore Viewrendering with dynamic datasource

Tags: sitecore, rendering, partial-views

Hi I have simple view rendering (e.g. with title and body).
While it works perfectly fine when i give a datasource to my rendering control in presentation layout - I am wondering if I can do it by code - i.e. define the data datasource by code.

Currently I have something like this that works just fine:

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<sample.Web.Models.sampleclass>
@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
        @Model.Title
    </div>
}
```

**Looking for something like below where i can define my datasource or the item**

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<sample.Web.Models.sampleclass>
@datasource  =  Sitecore.context.database.getitem("some different path or id"); 

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
          @Model.Title
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
@{
    var dynamicDatasource = new SitecoreContext().GetItem<sampleclass>(other_item_id)
}

@if (dynamicDatasource != null)
{
    <div>
        @Html.Glass().Editable(dynamicDatasource, d => d.Title)
    </div>
}
```